# How to show only ten results in vega-lite with this sorted chart

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

[image]

I have a chart sorted the way need but cannot seem to get rank to work.  I would like to show only the top ten with the existing sort...
so that George would be the last agent, for example.

[unranked](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqULKQI4aFWpRLiSQQzgQ0AbVBIycWZn0BhObLYAnRSCTEyAfWhPPXQATkoABijomNiI7yhTQX8oNgZHNABGJUEkJjhBfQA5PkwaUgACAHVPZUslZAAPQNSPEMyIpRw4DygHdXt9CMpQuLG47yC2-18euxCQABZKADYxcYmlKbgU0yghykXFydad1PSndAAmE+D-ZQt99GUaADNXitePNgQK3zJbtNur1+vMDos1htxiAAL4KWz2DLoAAyNEEAE9vP8WsF9AAOSJQ2IJJIpNJI7IgXL5QroEoUMqVGoeOreJo4tpZTogYF9Rxg9DDPFE6FbU4zUgeAVLVbrEXxMV3RKCJ4gYYAZmOium5yRIBu2p2D2g+he70+31+-0BO15oMGgsOkPl0Vh8J8iMuIAAUrUkPIlNjtvoAOyUOXykmCZK6y5XHJ5ArFUrlODVWr1EDs4OoDpdHp8gYLYYhiMuhUgbYSuYOmXOkU23Yqg5XUKN2P6A2V8XG1Vmj5fH5-PyNu382vDCFlyNwhH9fTe-16QN+DkLMPTqFRmPkuMJmnJhmp9MszPZ05c-Mg8fFyil8uuw3VqW15b1ontvYtttPjvXRu9qabwDpaw4Ak+Y5FuC74zu68x6gAonYgjLj4q45iAYYPtuZIXFk+5JnSKZMhmbJIM0OZ5jyBb2reIYPo+3Z3LML4LG+m6ikxOpfo6VxalxZy7p2AGPEB5qDlaI4QTRN7QRxW6zh687oL6qFBhe6ASNhSjKjueGoPGVKJrSID0mox7MqyDTkWul7UdeUGOvJH5Pix0rsS6n7No6ET8VWf76iJJrPMBFpDta0kOdKk4wQ2inwV6CEmAGaEBBhWnljhf6GdShGmcRaaWWeNmUdykHReGDFRI2bmvrKnm-jxaqRH54oBV2VaASF4mgRFAn+OVE5Os50LxZ6+gAOJwJ4gwrmlGkgBlDUgLpuFIjlxn6AAgrIEAAO49BUAAqNC6GRFEaWIV6FtKmSElVNWStKVx3pljXec1ELtkJ-5Pl1KihRJYGjjJjnNWIiwPWNykgAAskgHgUG0ThzbZmn3ZGOmkn+lK5SZO37YdJ1ndZF24qgV32TdtZ3VV1WuU9tYvfRy3+U1MXffpgV-aJ3UgeFUn9YNt4Q1DcHjeg8OIwjcAo6laOLRjDZY9Ga2XLjm1EUeJGnudaNUcLBwjRsj01mx9WY-1yqqsMvmc3qHU9rzAM9QL4FC6DFVTgxbpznqyJIAwUpYuhC3LNpK3Yz9GsHugBMHR4x2nah57k5ThuOsKD0M2bnavazbXs5QVwrPbXqO3c-39mFknu1WGfg5DPvQ4hyUh-N5MgOqlXLat2UEfju0J0nJNZiVl3XbRBwsz7OesXnM-K1bReZKXv4-dz-VV4DvWC-XntDaLzfizDAASFw9O3CvdxHffRwPh7mTrVlj2TnK5mVB+3uqdOm-P6AeUtmzD6-BhiZBDGXYSPNgou35rXEGUUhre2wi3L0qIMRXwwjfN6kdVY4wfnHIeRNk56xzOnL+BwVi-zns9fOQDC4fVtmvK2G8K7TG3q7eBkVqYiybigk+epFyyDUqHTu2De5R30htWOIB47ENHqnd+5DEG3iodnfqtUFjMxwcAm2kRmH+VYUFPsO83YIJ4UbPhmVUELjYCIju799Q90tnfKRBDZFEMTsTFO4806T1kk5ahGjGZaLoUvXR+hQEtUgb9Leztq5Az6vvFRlixZ+y9FNGa9iFYvWNjELKP1pF5TMoyQqpFSb60-ik3ieTNjBNzgAi24SGGqiiVcNhgkuYdPuPE0xXCPbVM+rFD8NiVJwHeJghauScGuPWu4uRXiSEVLIf4sGwxal1KrJoheOiWmRNtq1JURjoEmM4cDbhU8nJWM8qMkA59HCX1RhhF6t9JEUnmZ4kePi34hGURYx01yC7MRCTsoF3EQFgMOTqY5cSYEJN3nXcUDd1mArigIr0voWT+kmZ3O6GyKyzL3EZGRCyvmkInlTS5zUf7qK2SC64YSXLLwhcXKFnSHbGLEnA85Az-mNzSUpf2FhhDZIwnimZbyiV40fqUk8L9FHtCqXysB+LGJ0oaXWDZXlWkam6e1TlfMa48uScq4ax90n6GRMKmgoqFriokXgwpHzCaLIUb4pRqyKo0tnvU-+TjF5MoiegNpbK1ZQNhac7lSSkUUKuQKhKlrA7ByeXapWErHX6RjsUgqcrio-LssiygHRaXim2Y04ZYxtX7MoOqCB68ukGtgUa6NdxC3IOsei-QSEyAoRxY42mQTCX4WJXlUl3jyV+MpQE5qVwgnqr9dosFZwmpRM1DEzenVelnJbUCWN-LzWCoxeM14faFgDvUUOgy7iSkWXKa-SpnqhrFp9fO9yTTA17ODRqOtLCG0nK5c2veMbBkxVVfEW5rhZDuC8CmzuttB2SuHdKwhLqyXLIpYWumFZX1M0ZVud6Orwyhv1f+w1iSgOtr3SiqGABdOEKhHgeBoDgMoch9DeAcKkF4sgASaBAJiPj5EaCWD43jETmAPDmCUGUKAABrAAQv6ZQ+hCyPJADJ2TAB5HASAoB0AE9yMomBe3oDdCAV4NrBDKfQAmrYnhLigAswUazsjPQAAUKH0cwOibo+h3AIBoNoQoMJ6PwBoGQLAaBQAQEwHAHAWQVj0dyOiS+qAbAgE42wbjvHQCYDYGwQQZR4tpcc5ZlzW1PTOCSJmIzJncGCBqz5hYABHBg-ojNPz0IpJzVntp+Aq5gAAyheaTdA6v-AqMGaTTX9Ctfa3QTrvtzNlf0IYvCo3jMLG2I13z6A5uOAW6U2ENGlCNCix6MgbQGQLG2YGRowm0CyAYNGJQPWXOGzFKYEIoBlA-CQIF6wnRMh0ZC9ZDwsnzupEEJ4fQABiZQCPvB5YK0VtAEmpPqZm+gJgCMzMSf9BAV4ngEDWFAJdtIOAmACasIekAJ2QCSDYIFuwl3SghHS0gETsj+tkCGyN5bzn9DqVxEoNgxW0K5xhHR905OGCU+p7T+njPmdkFZ9d0nPgucVf6FV6MmY3sqcQ6L8X2ypdm-dJl7L53YuNAcwL3rcd3MUNe8TtQ+hi4AFJYT0eQOD87phwvyHQChV4ctkeFeY-oegaYEoVA+5j3b6m4C2+8GdimXmpS7SJx4EnJWQCy-l9YRXShlfaFV1dtQ7PbBa6dyk17K30Dx7F0LkFZvpegEt4FnLK0Csw746kWQLxWNB9yxYL0qhMAMAQFYAA5MN4IHmVG66gDPmjFQAA8FQKwmDMAsNoyn6M7-MPoVnDg8fJ7twb9A8+2iL54cv7w2fkBek90jrHIB9sdaO15-LEfivpavwjSRzGwWF7CYxY3YHkG6wbxABvzgDvynhdxzzd3QFfw23Gz8Em35280T0-0O1TGOx9wRgh0E2EDICDypHGTlhxwgAKECwWACwR17SUGUDTz4hd0cCqDgHC0i2xwK2U2k1-1R3QFixizf0TxtycAzwJyfw1wLypyLwTSVyZzLzV0rw10530DgIQJvAf3r0F3QAiWNxb0l3b3z2+DlwULS2LwZxUJZwr1iw0K520Od3txcxNUQJAGbxs1bzoz8PQIWHkzYGwCHG10cAqDgMzD2hoGUHoDQFnQiBhCAA)

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "Connor",
        "avg_score": "9.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.90000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.44",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Lily",
        "avg_score": "8.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.80000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.34",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jordan",
        "avg_score": "7.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.75000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.29",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jane",
        "avg_score": "7.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.75000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.29",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Eagle",
        "avg_score": "7.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.70000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Joe",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Evan",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "George",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.46",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Margaret",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.46",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Margaret",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Laura",
        "avg_score": "4.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.80000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.26",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Evan",
        "avg_score": "3.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.70000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Hunter",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.17",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Lily",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.06",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jane",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.06",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Joe",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "George",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.25000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.22",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jeff",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Hunter",
        "avg_score": "2.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.40000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.14",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jordan",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Leslie",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.15000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.32",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Leslie",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Laura",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.37",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Eagle",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.20000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.34",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jeff",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.37",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Connor",
        "avg_score": "0.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.54",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "agent",
      "sort": {"field": "AgentPercentage"},
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AgentCalls", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {
            "field": "AvgAgtScore",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          },
          {"field": "score_count", "title": "scores", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "percentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]}
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AvgAgtScore", "field": "avg_score", "op": "average"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentCalls", "field": "call_count", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "AgentPercentage", "format": ".2%"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "tooltip": "the agent percentage",
        "type": "text",
        "x": 5
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentPercentage", "field": "percentage", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "ScorePercentageCalc",
          "format": ".2%",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "score_desc", "title": "description"},
          {
            "field": "ScorePercentage",
            "format": ".2%",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "test",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentageCalc",
              "field": "score_calc",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentage",
              "field": "score_percentage",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "title": "Bottom Agent Scores",
  "width": 200
}
```

The accepted answer works perfectly, below is an Elixir implementation that replicates the json in that answer. I had no idea you could combine transforms on this way [in elixir].

```
   def create_bottom_agent_score_chart(score_stats) do
    data = Enum.map(score_stats, fn m -> Map.put(m, :score_desc, "diff from avg") end)

    Vl.new(width: 200, height: [step: 16], title: "Bottom Agent Scores", description: "")
    |> Vl.data_from_values(data, name: "data")
    |> Vl.transform(
      aggregate: [
        [field: "percentage", op: :average, as: "AgentPercentage"],
        [field: "call_count", op: :average, as: "AgentCalls"],
        [field: "avg_score", op: :average, as: "AvgAgtScore"],
        [field: "score_calc", op: :average, as: "ScorePercentageCalc"],
        [field: "score_percentage", op: :average, as: "ScorePercentage"],
        [field: "score_desc", op: :max, as: "score_desc"],
        [field: "score_count", op: :sum, as: "Scores"]
      ],
      groupby: ["agent"]
    )
    |> Vl.transform(
      window: [
        [
          op: "rank",
          as: "rank"
        ]
      ],
      sort: [[field: "AgentPercentage", order: "ascending"]]
    )
    |> Vl.transform(filter: "datum.rank < 11")
    |> Vl.encode_field(:y, "agent",
      type: :nominal,
      axis: [labels: true, tick_band: "center", tick_opacity: 0, title: ""],
      # sort: [op: "max", field: "percentage", order: "ascending"],
      sort: [field: "AgentPercentage", order: "ascending"]
    )
    |> Vl.layers([
      Vl.new()
      |> Vl.mark(:bar, tooltip: true, color: "#ddd")
      |> Vl.encode(:tooltip, [
        [field: "AgentCalls", type: :quantitative, title: "calls"],
        [field: "AvgAgtScore", type: :quantitative, title: "avg score"],
        [field: "Scores", type: :quantitative, title: "scores"]
      ])
      |> Vl.encode_field(:x, "AgentPercentage",
        # this agregate here is wierd, since the field is already averaged.
        # but it won't work without it...
        aggregate: :average,
        scale: [domain: [0, 1]],
        axis: nil
      ),
      Vl.new()
      |> Vl.mark(:text, align: "left", x: 5, tooltip: "the agent percentage")
      |> Vl.encode_field(:text, "AgentPercentage", format: ".1%"),
      Vl.new()
      |> Vl.mark(:text,
        align: "left",
        baseline: "middle",
        dx: 24,
        font_weight: :bold,
        tooltip: "test"
      )
      |> Vl.encode(:tooltip, [
        [field: "score_desc", title: "description"],
        [field: "ScorePercentage", type: :quantitative, title: "avg score", format: ".1%"]
      ])
      |> Vl.encode_field(:text, "ScorePercentageCalc",
        type: :quantitative,
        format: ".1%"
      )
      |> Vl.encode(:color,
        value: "green",
        condition: [test: "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0", value: "red"]
      )
    ])
    |> Vl.to_spec()
    |> Jason.encode!()
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing all your transforms up front and in one go. You're also duplicating values which is why your text is bolder (values placed one upon the other).

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "Connor",
        "avg_score": "9.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.90000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.44",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Lily",
        "avg_score": "8.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.80000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.34",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jordan",
        "avg_score": "7.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.75000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.29",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jane",
        "avg_score": "7.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.75000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.29",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Eagle",
        "avg_score": "7.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.70000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Joe",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Evan",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "George",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.46",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Margaret",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.46",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Margaret",
        "avg_score": "5.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Laura",
        "avg_score": "4.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.80000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.26",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Evan",
        "avg_score": "3.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.70000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Hunter",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.17",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Lily",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.06",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jane",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.06",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Joe",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "George",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.25000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.22",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jeff",
        "avg_score": "2.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.50000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.04",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Hunter",
        "avg_score": "2.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.40000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.14",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jordan",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Leslie",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.15000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.32",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Leslie",
        "avg_score": "1.5000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.30000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.24",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Laura",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.37",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Eagle",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.20000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.34",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Jeff",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 2,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.6500000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.37",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46500000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Connor",
        "avg_score": "0.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 1,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.00000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.7000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.54",
        "score_count": "2",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.54000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "average", "field": "percentage", "as": "AgentPercentage"},
        {"op": "average", "field": "score_calc", "as": "ScorePercentageCalc"},
        {"op": "average", "field": "call_count", "as": "AgentCalls"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["agent"]
    },
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "AgentPercentage", "order": "ascending"}],
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank < 11"}
  ],
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "agent",
      "sort": {"field": "AgentPercentage"},
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AgentCalls", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {
            "field": "AgentPercentage",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          },
          {"field": "score_count", "title": "scores", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "axis": null,
          "field": "AgentPercentage",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]}
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "AgentPercentage", "format": ".2%"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "tooltip": "the agent percentage",
        "type": "text",
        "x": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "ScorePercentageCalc",
          "format": ".2%",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "score_desc", "title": "description"},
          {
            "field": "ScorePercentage",
            "format": ".2%",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "test",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Bottom Agent Scores",
  "width": 200
}
```